# Install locuplot on Amazon Linux

Tags: python, pip, locust

My experience in python is close to 0, bear with me.

I want to install https://pypi.org/project/locuplot/ on an EC2 machine to create some plots after running Locust in headless mode.

However, I do not manage to install it:

```
yum update -y
yum install python3 -y
yum install python3-devel -y
yum install python3-pip -y
yum install python-pip -y
yum -y groupinstall 'Development Tools'
pip3 install locust
pip install locuplot
```

But the last command results in:

```
Collecting locuplot
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement locuplot (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for locuplot
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Is the last line really `pip install` instead of `pip3 install`?

Comment: Also check the exact python version, I am not sure what is available on the ec2 machines: `python3 --version`. To use locuplot it needs to be >=3.8

Comment: that was the problem, would you like to put it as answer so I can accept it?

Comment: the actual problem is the python version, that gotta be >=3.8

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
pip install locuplot
```

in your last line, but `locuplot` does only work with python3 and, depending on your setup, `pip` might default to the python2 installation, so you should do

```
pip3 install locuplot
```

instead

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to FlyingTeller found the issue.

The reason is that it requires python>=3.8

```
 amazon-linux-extras install python3
 python3.8 -m pip install locuplot
 pip install locuplot
```